# Automatic installation of browser-plugins

Tags: internet-explorer, deployment, opera, browser-plugin, firebreath

I've wrote NPRuntime/ActiveX plugin using FireBreath. I've done automatic installation from web-page for Firefox and Google Chrome, but I can't do it for opera and IE. Please, help me to understand how to do it.

Edit: Now I'm trying to make WiX installer for it, but I see no *.msi file in project directory after building only plugin with dll extension. I've installed Wix and VS2010. So plugin is building and working correctly, but there is no Installer project in solution and msi installer in results. Please, help me to fix it.

Comment: If you are having trouble with FireBreath specifically, you could always ask on the [user group](http://groups.google.com/group/firebreath-dev). You should also ask a new question for the WiX/MSI problem as it doesn't have to do anything with the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE [does not support NPAPI plugins](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303401/en-us).  You need to write an [Active X](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751972(VS.85).aspx) wrapper.

Edit: According to the FireBreath documentation you need to use an MSI to install on Windows, so it would seem automatic installation isn't an option with this framework.

The correct way to do automatic installation of an Active X control is to build a cab file and install via the <object> tag.  You may be able to get this to work.  See [Packaging ActiveX Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751974(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: @user: Then you should mention that you are using a combined NPAPI/ActiveX plugin - its not clear from your question.

Comment: Minor addition: The MSI installer is not *needed* with FireBreath, but most easily done as its already generated for you and has the advantage of maintaining only one installer for all browsers. :)

Comment: To confirm Georg's comment, you can install a firebreath plugin using regsvr32 or anything else that calls DllRegisterServer() on the DLL

Answer (score 1):

Opera doesn't support automated install. You need to provide a .msi or .exe installer for users to download and run.

Comment: And what about using widjet for this purpose?

Comment: Interesting thought, not sure if a widget is allowed to install software though.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips on building an MSI via the Firebreath framework (see my response):
[FireBreath plugin automatic installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122437/firebreath-plugin-automatic-installation)

May I inquire about how you achieved automated plugin installation in Firefox and Chrome? That would be awesome :)

Edit: .XPI package for Firefox, .CRX package for Chrome.